# c++ reference to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, crash, gdi+

I have the following pseudocode:

```
function1()//Gets called on startup
{
    myclass* obj;
    function2(obj);
    obj->doSomething();//crashes here!
}

function2(myclass*& ret)
{
    myclass* nobj = &myclass();
    nobj->doSomething();//Does not crash
    ret = &nobj;
}
```

It would appear that even though I am setting ret to point to nobj, when I try to operate on obj (which should be pointing to nobj, as ret is a reference to obj), my program crashes! Clearly I am doing something wrong, anyone know what it is?

Comment: Where is `ret` declared?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER function2(myclass*& ret)

Comment: Ah seems I need to sleep more!

Comment: Is this really the code you are using? Do you get warnings about incompatible pointer types?

Comment: Still, aren't you missing `new` or it's a pseudocode issue?

Comment: @sth this is not the EXACT code I am using. This is basically a watered down version of my method. All the initializations are exactly the same, as well as how I am calling my methods. Not to mention classes and methods are renamed. No warnings about incompatible pointer types

Comment: `ret = &nobj` shouldn't compile like this...

Comment: @sth Apparently my compiler doesn't think so. I am using Eclipse, so it may be filtering some of the warnings out, not sure.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER I was operating under the false pretense that if you set a pointer to point to a method-scoped variable, the scope becomes lifted -- like what would have happened if I were *returning* obj, not setting ret to it.

Comment: It shouldn't be just a warning but an error (two errors actually) - time to update your compiler :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie Hah. Probably...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are taking the address of a temporary by doing `&myclass()`, which is a no-no because the temporary is destroyed at the end of the expression, and your compiler shouldn't allow it.

Although your compiler is nonconformant in that area already, you are going on to use a destructed object, which is undefined behaviour and is why your code crashes.

Also, I'm not sure how you are assigning a pointer to a pointer to a `myclass` (`&nobj`) to a pointer to a `myclass` (`ret`). It shouldn't compile.

Comment: We meet again! Interesting. I would need to use new then, and just be sure to deallocate it when I'm done with it?

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen yes, or more preferably use `new` with smart pointers so you don't have to worry about cleaning it up

Comment: Ahah, thank you once again :) I will accept you in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
myclass *obj = new myclass();
obj->doSomething();
delete obj;
```